# Why does the second order delta method approximation to the variance of Bernoulli r.v. result in a negative chi-square?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Let $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ be iid Bernoulli random variables with parameter $p$. Suppose we estimate the variance $Var(Y_1) = p(1-p)$ using $\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})$ where $\hat{p}=\bar{Y}_n$. I am trying to obtain the asymptotic distribution for this estimator **specifically** in the case where $p=\frac{1}{2}$. In the $p = \frac{1}{2}$ case, the first derivative is zero, hence we use the second order delta method:

Suppose that $\sqrt{n}(T_n-\theta_0) \to_D Z$ and that we are interested in $g(T_n)$ where $g'(\theta_0) = 0$ but $g''$ is continuous and nonzero in a neighborhood of $\theta_0$. Then $\sqrt{n}(g(T_n)-g(\theta_0))$ has a degenerate limiting distribution, but:

$$
$\sqrt{n}(g(T_n)-g(\theta_0)) \to_D \frac{g''(\theta_0)}{2}Z^2
$$

So, using this I have that for $p =\frac{1}{2}$, $g'(p) = 0$, but $g''(p) = -2 \neq 0$, so:

$$
n\left(\hat{p}(1-\hat{p})-\frac{1}{4}\right) \to_D -\frac{1}{4}\chi^2_1
$$

I am wondering why this negative limit makes sense. I read in a footnote somewhere that this makes sense since $p(1-p)$ is maximized at $p=\frac{1}{2}$, but this doesn't really register with me. Can anyone help me here? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $p(1 - p) \le \frac{1}{4}$ for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$, so you always have $p(1-p) - \frac{1}{4} \le 0$. This is where the negative sign comes from.

Now for large $n$, $\hat p(1 - \hat p)$ will be close to $\frac{1}{4}$ by the law of large numbers. But in a typical case, you don't have an exact equality $\hat p = \frac{1}{2}$, but only $\hat p \approx \frac{1}{2}$. This means that in a typical case we have strict inequality $\hat p (1 - \hat p) - \frac{1}{4} < 0$.

Now how "strong" is this strict inequality? Well, if we rescale this difference by a factor of $n$, we get a nondegenerate limiting distribution, i.e. $n(\hat p(1 - \hat p) - \tfrac{1}{4}) \to -\frac{1}{4} \chi^2_1$.

Comment: When you allude to how "strong" it is, what do you mean by that? Do you mean how well it holds asymptotically? thanks!

Comment: I mean how big the order of the difference between $\hat p (1 - \hat p) - \frac{1}{4}$ and $0$ is. For example, $-\frac{1}{n}$ and $-\frac{1}{n^2}$ are both negative numbers. But the first one goes linearly to zero, while the second one goes quadratically to zero. This is essentially what I mean by the order.